# Windows touchscreen stuck right clicking

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, windows-tabletpc

I have an issue with my only windows machine. It is a smarttab (some cheap Chinese thing) running Windows 10. It has a touchscreen. The touchscreen worked fine for a while but suddenly it only knows how to right click. Every single click is right click, double click is right then left click, two finger click attempts dragging things around. 
The behavior should be single click is left click, two finger click is right, double click is just a double click

I've

*Edit* Since most of this post got cut off somehow (see lonely "I've" above), Ill add that ive tried every thing from re-enabling drivers to checking for/updating and restarting machine, none work, even for the brief period others report it working, no dice for me. I have also tried regular right clicking as other places have suggested to no luck, as well as "scrubbing" the screen (dragging all ten fingers around the screen at once).

Im scared to try installing linux on it, because its a cheap chinese P.o.S. with a non-standard bios and im not sure if it will survive the process, or be usable after. But if anyone knows of linux working on 2-in-1 pcs (preferably arch linux, second preferably buntu), im down to give it a try

Comment: Look for debris in the frame of the touch screen would be my suggestion.  Something is possibly trapped at the edge making the screen think that it is doing 'touch and hold'.. just a guess.

Comment: Just took put the screen back on, it was cleaner before i got there. I think its something with windows drivers. Touch works as expected on windows app used with touch (3d paint, sticky notes, screen drawing) but for everything else both single finger and two finger (left and right click) perform a right click, while double tapping just does two right clicks (unless i do it fast enough, then the second is a regular left click but with no accuracy due to flailing on the screen just to get it). Dragging performs a right click drag, regardless of the fingers used

Comment: and, I just noticed, a majority of my post got.. cut off? I had typed three paragraphs but only got one and the first word of the second. Unfortunately have no backup of the original, but whats here pretty much sums it up, expect ive tried re-enabling drivers, updates, etc. The first two pages of google were no help on this pretty much